# Doctrine: Why can't I free memory when accessing entities through an association?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an `Application` that has a relationship to `ApplicationFile`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ApplicationFile",
 *   mappedBy="application",
 *   cascade={"remove"},
 *   orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 */
private $files;
```

A file entity has a field that stores binary data, and can be up to 2MB in size. When iterating over a large list of applications and their files, PHP memory usage grows. I want to keep it down.

I've tried this:

```
$applications = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Application')->findAll();
foreach ($applications as $app) {
  ...
  foreach ($app->getFiles() as $file) {
    ...
    $this->em->detach($file);
  }
  $this->em->detach($app);
}
```

Detaching the object should tell the entity manager to stop caring about this object and de-referencing it, but it surprisingly has no effect on the amount of memory usage - it keeps increasing.

Instead, I have to manually load the application files (instead of retrieving them through the association method), and the memory usage does not increase. This works:

```
$applications = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Application')->findAll();
foreach ($applications as $app) {
  ...

  $appFiles = $this
      ->em
      ->getRepository('AppBundle:ApplicationFile')
      ->findBy(array('application' => $application));

  foreach ($appFiles as $file) {
    ...
    $this->em->detach($file);
  }
  $this->em->detach($app);
}
```

I used `xdebug_debug_zval` to track references to the `$file` object. In the first example, there's an extra reference somewhere, which explains why memory is ballooning - PHP is not able to garbage collect it!

Does anyone know why this is? Where is this extra reference and how do I remove it?

**EDIT**: Explicitly calling `unset($file)` at the end of its loop has no effect. There are still TWO references to the object at this point (proven with `xdebug_debug_zval`). One contained in `$file` (which I can unset), but there's another somewhere else that I cannot unset. Calling `$this->em->clear()` at the end of the main loop has no effect either.

**EDIT 2: SOLUTION**: The answer by @origaminal led me to the solution, so I accepted his answer instead of providing my own.

In the first method, where I access the files through the association on `$application`, this has a side effect of initializing the previously uninitialized `$files` collection on the `$application` object I'm iterating over in the outer loop.

Calling `$em->detach($application)` and `$em->detach($file)` only tells Doctrine's UOW to stop tracking the objects, but it doesn't affect the array of `$applications` I'm iterating on, which now have populated collection of `$files` which eat up memory.

I have to unset each `$application` object after I'm done with it to remove all references to the loaded `$files`. To do this, I modified the loops as such:

```
    $applications = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Application')->findAll();
    $count = count($applications);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        foreach ($applications[$i]->getFiles() as $file) {
            $file->getData();
            $em->detach($file);
            unset($file);
        }
        $em->detach($applications[$i]);
        unset($applications[$i]);

        // Don't NEED to force GC, but doing so helps for testing.
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
```

Comment: By default collection associations are marked as `LAZY` meaning that they would most likely get loaded into memory if accessed even once. Try adding `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` to your annotation. `EXTRA_LAZY`  means that your collection will be loaded **only** when it's being called. If this doesn't help we will think of something else.

Comment: @Brian you mean you store your application file in database ? You should store it on disk, and just store path to file on disk.

Comment: @Nico, yes, storing small files as blobs in the database. It's small amount (less than 1,000), and the files are usually less than 1MB. Data integrity is very important, but we may consider moving them to the filesystem.

Comment: ok Brian I understand it was just a suggestion, I don't know which is the best for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are speaking about your first implementation you have extra links to the collection in the `PersistentCollection::coll` of the `Application::files` property - this object is created by Doctrine on `Application` instantiation.

With detach you are just deleting `UoW` links to the object.

There are different ways to fix this but a lot of hacks should be applied. Most nice way probably to detach also `Application` object and unset it.

But it is still preferable to use more advanced ways for a [batch processing](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/batch-processing.html#batch-processing): some were listed in the other answer. The current way forces doctrine to make use proxies and throws extra queries to DB to get the files of the current object.

**Edit**

The difference between the first and the second implementation is that there are no circular references in the second case: `Application::files` stays with uninitialized `PersistenceCollection` (with no elements in `coll`).

To check this - can you try to drop the files association explicitly?

Comment: But I am also detaching the application object as well, so this can't be it. The loop should immediately overwrite `$app`, and even if it wasn't, I've tried a variation where I explicitly `unset($app)` as well, but it has no effect.

Comment: Yes, I got it but it looks like as circular references problem. App contains references to Files through collection, File references App and so on (2nd implementation doesn't have that cause Collection is uninitialized). You can check it by unsetting of the files `Collection` manually, e.g. `unset($app->files)`

Comment: This answer ultimately led me to the solution. In the first method, calling `$app->getFiles()` will initialize the `$files` collection on the `$application` object. So, even though I tell Doctrine to detach the `$application` and `$file` objects, there's still an active reference to these objects contained in the `$applications` array. Unsetting the array value for the specific `$application` object removes all references and allows PHP to garbage collect. I will update the question with a better explanation.

Answer (score 4):

#### Cascade

`EntityManager::detach` should indeed remove all references Doctrine has to the enities. But it does *not* do the same for associated entities *automatically*.

You need to *cascade* this action by adding `detach` the `cascade` option of the association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *   targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ApplicationFile",
 *   mappedBy="application",
 *   cascade={"remove", "detach"},
 *   orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 */
private $files;
```

Now `$em->detach($app)` should be enough to remove references to the `Application` entity as well as its associated `ApplicationFile` entities.

#### Find vs Collection

I highly doubt that loading the `ApplicationFile` entities through the association, in stead of using the repository to `findBy()` them, is the source of your issue.

Sure that when loaded through the association, the Collection will have a reference to those child-entities. But when the parent entity is dereferenced, the entire tree will be garbage collected, unless there are other references to those child entities.

I suspect the code you show is pseudo/example code, not the actual code in production. Please examine that code thoroughly to find those other references.

#### Clear

Sometimes it worth clearing the entire EntityManager and merging a few entities back in. You could try `$em->clear()` or `$em->clear('AppBundle\Entity\ApplicationFile')`.

#### Clear has no effect

You're saying that clearing the EntityManager has no effect. This means the references you're searching for are *not* within the EntityManager (of UnitOfWork), because you've just cleared that.

#### Doctrine but not Doctrine

Are you using any event-listeners or -subscribers? Any filters? Any custom mapping types? Multiple EntityManagers? Anything else that could be integrated into Doctrine or its life-cycle, but is not necessarily part of Doctrine itself?

Especially event-listeners/subscribers are often overlooked when searching for the source of issues. So I'd suggest you start to look there.

Comment: I understand that detaching is not cascaded by default, but I am explicitly detaching the associated entity each time in the loop. Even modifying the relationship to `cascade={"remove", "detach"},` as you wrote has no effect. The code I am showing is almost exactly what I'm using. In my tests just now, I strip everything except for the looping and the detaching, and memory still climbs. Finally, calling `$em->clear()` has no effect either.

Comment: You state that `$em->clear()` has no effect, which clearly demonstrates that the references are _not_ within the EntityManager / UnitOfWork (that you've just cleared). Are you using any events, listeners/subscribers, filters, custom mapping types, etc? Anything that's used by Doctrine which could hold references to your entities?

Comment: No, nothing out of the ordinary here that I can see. It seems to me the problem must be in the way Doctrine is loading `$files`. If I manually query for the files, I can account for every reference and control memory. If I get files thru the Doctrine relationship `$app->getFiles()`, then there's an extra reference I cannot find.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in PHP's garbage collector, that works a bit odd. First off all each time the scripts need memory it will allocate memory from RAM, even if you use `unset()`, `$object = null`, or other tricks to free the memory, the allocated memory will not be returned to Operating System till the script is not finished and the process associated with it killed.

**How to fix that** ?

1. *Usually is done on Linux Systems*
   Create commands that runs the needed script with `limit`, `offset` parameters and re-run the needed scripts in small batches more times. In this way, the script will use less memory, and each time the memory will be freed when the script will be finished.
2. Get rid of `Doctrine` it balloons by himself the memory, `PDO` is much faster and less costly.

Comment: I can force PHP to garbage collect using `gc_collect_cycles`, but that's not the problem. The problem is that there's some reference to the Doctrine entity that is not release, so PHP will not garbage collect it until the script ends. My question is WHY that extra reference exists, where it exists, and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Why do so many people advocate that Doctrine is inefficient when it comes down to memory?! I've created processes that handle hundreds of thousands (up to millions) of entities with a peak memory usage of 20MB. It's not Doctrine that's memory inefficient, it's developers using it wrong that cause these issues...

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of task where objects in memory could lead to that leaks, you should use [Doctrine2 iterators](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#id1)

```
$appFiles = $this
      ->em
      ->getRepository('AppBundle:ApplicationFile')
      ->findBy(array('application' => $application));
```

should be refactored in order to return a `query` object and not an `ArrayCollection`, then from that query object, you can easily call `iterate()` method and clean the memory after every object inspection

### Edit

You have "hidden references" because `detach` operation will not delete the object in memory, it only tells to `EntityManager` not to handle it anymore. This is why you should use my solution or `unset()` the object with php function.

Comment: Well, my issue is the first approach I was taking. I'm just wondering why there is some hidden reference to the `$file` that I can't seem to remove.

Comment: @Brian: Take a look to my "Edit" explaination

Comment: unsetting the variables doesn't matter either. The vars are being re-assigned on each iteration of the loop. But even explicitly calling `unset($file)` before I loop again has no effect. There's an additional reference to `$file` that I cannot remove, I confirmed this using `xdebug_debug_zval` to check the reference count.